# log4j is printing logs in .nfsXXXX instead of .log files

Tags: java, linux, logging, log4j, nfs

I'm trying to create logs with log4j but instead .nfsXXXX files are getting generated in which the logs are printed.
Can someone please guide me why these files are getting generated and how to prevent them.
I'm using linus

logging.properties content:

```
log4j.logger.errorLogger=debug, E
log4j.additivity.errorLogger=false
log4j.appender.E=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.E.File=Error.log
log4j.appender.E.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.E.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.E.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.E.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} : %-5p] - %m%n%n


log4j.logger.consoleLogger=debug, C
log4j.additivity.consoleLogger=false
log4j.appender.C=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.C.File=Console.log
log4j.appender.C.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.C.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.C.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.C.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} : %-5p] - %m%n%n

log4j.logger.transactionLogger=debug, T
log4j.additivity.transactionLogger=false
log4j.appender.T=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.T.File=Transaction.log
log4j.appender.T.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.T.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.T.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.T.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} : %-5p] - %m%n


log4j.logger.XMLLogger=debug, X
log4j.additivity.XMLLogger=false
log4j.appender.X=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.X.File=XML.log
log4j.appender.X.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.X.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.X.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.X.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} : %-5p] - %m%n%n
```

Comment: `logging.properties` is the name of the default `java.util.logging` configuration file. Log4j's (version 1.2) default configuration file is called `log4j.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

> log4j is printing logs in .nfsXXXX instead of .log files

What you should use is the code below and substitue `myFileName.log` with your target file name.

```
log4j.appender.X=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.X.fileName=myFileName.log
```

You need to do this for all appenders that you declare in your `logging.properties` file

Comment: There is not Java Bean property called `fileName` (cf. [javadoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html)). Although the private field is named `fileName` the setter is called just `setFile`, hence `file` in OP's configuration file is correct.